Increasingly Large Spacing Between Rows in a RecyclerView in a ConstraintLayout
The spacing between rows in my RecyclerView becomes increasingly large. Setting layout_height to wrap_content didn't seem to fix this common spacing issue.
XML of recycler row:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp" >

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/listing_checkBox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/address_textView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/listing_checkBox"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:text="@string/text_address_preview" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/price_textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/listing_checkBox"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/address_textView"
                tools:text="@string/text_price_preview" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/listing_imageView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/address_textView"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/apartment1" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

XML of activity where recycler is used:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".ApartmentActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/apartmentRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

In the activity, the RecyclerView is using a LinearLayoutManager like so:
recyclerView.adapter = adapter
recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)

Other than that, there's no programmatic styling.
Images visualizing issue:

Between Row 1 & 2
Between Row 2 & 3

I've tried setting layout_height to wrap_content, and changing the ConstraintLayout to a RelativeLayout, however, the spacing issue still persists.
